# Help with ゃったって and なん

Tags: grammar, meaning, no-da

I need help to understand some grammar in this sentence

```
何度ゃったって
結果は同じだ
それが世界の真理なんだ
```

So I translated it for "no matter how many times I will try, the result will be the same. that's the truth of this world"

But there are two things that I don't understand here:

1. ゃったって? where it came from? te iru form of やる (to do)? Because I know there is どうゃったって - what do you saying
2. なんだ? is that to explain ton or something?

Thanks,
Or

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why is your translation spot-on if you do not understand two parts of the original?

This 「って」 is the colloquial form of 「とて」, which means "even if".

https://jisho.org/search/%E3%81%A8%E3%81%A6

「なんだ」 is the colloquial form of 「なのだ」, which is a sentence-ender expressing a firm kind of declaration/affirmation.

Comment: Thanks, I understood the context well. was I right that ゃった is やる？

Comment: Why are you using a small ゃ instead of the regular や? It doesn't make sense in this context.

Comment: Probably my mistake...